# Create table query gives me "table does not exists" error

Tags: database

My local Drupal site is crashed, and it shows this error:

> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal722.semaphore' doesn't exist: SELECT expire, value FROM {semaphore} WHERE name = :name; Array ( [:name] => variable_init ) in lock_may_be_available() (line 167 of D:\Projects\wamp\www\drupal\includes\lock.inc).
>
> Uncaught exception thrown in shutdown function.
> PDOException: SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'drupal722.semaphore' doesn't exist: DELETE FROM {semaphore} WHERE (value = :db_condition_placeholder_0) ; Array ( [:db_condition_placeholder_0] => 573260675528605a31630a6.23576489 ) in lock_release_all() (line 269 of D:\Projects\wamp\www\drupal\includes\lock.inc).

I googled about how to solve this error, and I found that I need to create a table. So I used the following query to create a table.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `semaphore` (
    `name` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'Primary Key: Unique name.',
    `value` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '' COMMENT 'A value for the semaphore.',
    `expire` double NOT NULL COMMENT 'A Unix timestamp with microseconds indicating when the semaphore should expire.',
    PRIMARY KEY (`name`),
    KEY `value` (`value`),
    KEY `expire` (`expire`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COMMENT='Table for holding semaphores, locks, flags, etc. that...';`
```

With my surprise, it is giving the following error. (`drupal722` is my database name.)

> 1146 - Table 'drupal722.semaphore' doesn't exist

1. Why is the create table query giving me the "table does not exists" error? It is much obvious that i know that table does not exists and so i want to create table and so i am firing a query of `Create table`.
2. How do I resolve the above mentioned error related to Drupal, and get my site back to work?

Comment: Please check your `settings.php` file. May be something like `host` is not configured properly.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: i have checked settings.php. host is `localhost`. I think, thats fine. Right?

Comment: @BhavikShah, You need to check your `host` value with `host` value of `mysql` server. If you are saying its fine, then it will be fine. I am surprised with your error `#1146 - Table 'drupal722.semaphore' doesn't exist`. If there is no `table` then, table should created. You can try `CREATE TABLE` without `IF NOT EXISTS`.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: Exactly my point. I have checked that host is `localhost` which is corrent value and table does not exists. But still i am getting this error. I have even googled this but didn't found anything useful

Comment: Can you CREATE any table??

Comment: @BhavikShah, are you able to create table in any other database or any other table in same database?

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: Yes. I can create table with different name and same schema.

Comment: @davidstrachan:Yes. I can create table with different name and same schema.

Comment: Try `CREATE TABLE` without `IF NOT EXISTS`

Comment: @BhavikShah, Please try the suggestion of `david strachan`

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: i have tried `david strachan` suggestion but same problem persists...

Comment: @davidstrachan: i have tried firing the query as you have suggested but i am getting same error. After trying various things, i think the problem is the `table name`

Comment: @BhavikShah, then there is some issue in your `database`. May be, its corrupted or may be some other issue. Try to export `database table` and import into another database and setup drupal with new database.

Comment: @BhavikShah, I do not think that there is any issue with `table name` as its standard table of `drupal`.

Comment: @JayendraKainthola: but if i change the tablename and fire create table query with same schema that everything works fine and table gets created

Comment: TRY [SHOW TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/getting-information.html)

Comment: @davidstrachan: when i fired `Show tables` in console, it showed `semaphore` along with the list of other tables. But no operation is allowed. Neither select nor rename operation works...

Comment: @BhavikShah "But no operation is allowed." - that's the reason. You don't have permissions to run requests with this database. Can you login as root and dump all the tables from your database?

Comment: @user4035: If i / user dont have permission then the error message should be different. And moreover, i can do all kind of operations on every table except this.

Comment: @BhavikShah It's hard to say, what's corrupted there. Is it possible to dump the whole database to a file. Then drop the current database and recreate it from scratch?

Comment: @user4035: Yes, it is possible as i have already mentioned in question that this is my localhost project. But, i am so eager to find the solution of this answer is because i can't drop the database and re-create it from scratch for live projects. So, i have to find the solution to this problem.

Comment: @BhavikShah I see. Can we do this: you'll dump a database, but do not drop the current one. Then you create a fresh DB, put the data from file into it. Then change the DB in settings.php - we'll see, whether this solution worked. Then we'll try to investigate, what's wrong with the old db. I think, it's MySQL, and not Drupal issue.